# Tensorflow: TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file'

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to run the pet detector google cloud example seen here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md, and get most of the way though until I actually try to run the training, until I run the command:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training `whoami`_object_detection_`date +%s` \
  --runtime-version 1.2 \
  --job-dir=gs://test-run-2/train \
  --packages dist/object_detection-0.1.tar.gz,slim/dist/slim-0.1.tar.gz \
  --module-name object_detection.train \
  --region us-central1 \
  --config object_detection/samples/cloud/cloud.yml \
  -- \
  --train_dir=gs://test-run-2/train \
  --pipeline_config_path=gs://test-run-2/data/pipeline.config
```

Which inevitably leads to the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/train.py", line 49, in <module>
    from object_detection import trainer
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/trainer.py", line 27, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import preprocessor_builder
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/builders/preprocessor_builder.py", line 21, in <module>
    from object_detection.protos import preprocessor_pb2
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/object_detection/protos/preprocessor_pb2.py", line 71, in <module>
    options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file'
```

I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong here or where that error comes from, as I can't see inside the preprocessor_pb2.py file. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Running into similar issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@olive_tree has a good answer, what ended up being my issue was the version of protobuf I was compiling with. Make sure you protoc version matches the correct one described here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md

This is what I ended up having to run (on OSX)

```
brew uninstall protobuf
brew install protobuf@2.6
```

voila, problems solved!

Comment: I strongly recommend people using Ubuntu "not to follow" this. Uninstalling or removing `protobuf`is a dangerous thing to do, it may lead to a system crash.

Answer (score 2):

I met this issue after upgrading tensorflow to version 1.11 and solved it by running:
    `pip install --upgrade protobuf`

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue- it is likely due to using an updated tensorflow dist (1.4) while trying to run the job on 1.2.  I solved it by passing in a yaml config file that sets it:

```
trainingInput:
  runtimeVersion: "1.4"
  pythonVersion: "3.5"
```

If you run into matplot lib import error, you'll need to follow: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2739#issuecomment-351213863 for now until tensorflow models repo fixes it.